# Colouring extreme outliers in a boxplot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, outliers

I have used ggplot2 to create a boxplot. I want the 'extreme' outliers (identified by the `is_extreme` function) to be in a different colour to the other outliers.

Here is my code:

```
ggplot(Mooney_data) + geom_boxplot(aes(x=Phase, y=RT), outlier.colour='red')+geom_point(data=Mooney_data[is_extreme(Mooney_data$RT),], aes(x= Phase, y=RT, col=factor(is_extreme(RT))))+ theme(legend.position='none')+mytheme
```

This gives me the extreme outliers in blue. However, I don't understand why the rest of the outliers are in two different shades of red? How can I correct this?

[image: Boxplots with extreme outliers coloured in blue]

Comment: My advice to you; although its possible to inline transform your data while in your graphical plotting code; its almost always a bad idea, and a way to make everything harder for yourself. Best practice is to transform your data and prepare all your input(s) first, and then write as pure plotting code as you can; this separation of concerns will save you much pain over the years.

Comment: @NirGraham thank you; any advice on how to resolve this?

Comment: You have to put the `col` outside of the `geom_point` aesthetic and make it a constant color, such as blue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting two different shades of red because the default color scheme for ggplot with two factor levels is `hue_pal()(2)`, the first of which is the shade of red you are seeing in addition to the 'red' that you have specified for outliers.

```
library(scales)
hue_pal()(2)
[1] "#F8766D" "#00BFC4"
```

If you want blue extreme outliers, put the `col` argument outside of the `geom_point` aesthetic:

```
geom_point(data=Mooney_data[is_extreme(Mooney_data$RT),], 
aes(x= Phase, y=RT), 
col='blue'))  # <--- here
```